# How to implement MSAL SSO in Android using Microsoft Authenticator instead of a browser

Tags: android, azure, single-sign-on, azure-ad-msal

We are developing 10+ mobile apps for our organization's internal purposes. We use Azure AD so we are trying to implement SSO for all android apps using Microsoft identity platform(v2.0). We couldn't make Microsoft authenticator as the Broker app instead of the browser view.
Please help us on how to achieve this.

I checked out the Microsoft identity platform(v2.0) documentation regarding this but no use.

Comment: Have you achieved this? If so, please explain how.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [MSAL for Android](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-android) code, looks like you need to set the [`broker_redirect_uri_registered`](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-android/blob/dev/msal/src/main/res/raw/msal_default_config.json#L14) value to `true` in your `auth_config.json` (refer [sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-android-native/blob/master/app/src/main/res/raw/auth_config.json)) file for the broker to be used.

PS: I haven't tried this myself either... *yet*.

Comment: I tried it but it's not working. It opens a webview inside the app for sign-in rather than launching the Microsoft Authenticator app for the sign-in.